# NASM dd label - label?

Tags: assembly, nasm

Assume the following code in NASM

```
global _offset
_offset:
  dd _base_ptr-_entry_point
```

I get that the instruction assembles two 4-byte constants. But does this mean it will compute the difference between the return values of these 2 functions, or the difference between their actual addresses in memory, at runtime?

Comment: NASM can compute expressions at assemble time, granted they respect its constrains on [critical expressions](https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.8). In this case, the DWORD has the value of the delta between the two labels' addresses.

Comment: "assembles two 4-byte constants." Wrong, it assembles one 4-byte (dword) value.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Thanks for that one! So it stores the difference between addresses not their return value. Got it!

Comment: @randomuser843 Glad to help. Note that their address it's all labels have. No code is run at assemble time (it would be impossible) so NASM cannot know the return value of a function or the value of a location in memory (e.g. a `dd`, let's call it a "variable"). Though NASM could know the initial values of variables, that would only be problematic. Constants can be used instead (see `%define`).